# Sidekiq Parent batch to wait until child batch's all jobs complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I want to create a work flow in which a Sidekiq worker spawns a batch job in which there will again be a list of workers to be spawned and completed and only after these child workers are fully executed, I would like to run the callback(on_complete) for the parent batch.

Basically, I want to achieve this workflow

So, I researched about sidekiq batches from the documentation [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Complex-Job-Workflows-with-Batches) and [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Really-Complex-Workflows-with-Batches)

However, both the above resources are mentioning a workflow which expects a step of Job to be completed first then move on to the other step using Sidekiq Batches.

In my requirement, I wan't to create batches inside each individual batch job, and then do some work in the main batch's callback once all the child batches are done processing.

Please see below snippet, I have tried to make it as clear as I can. If additional info is needed, please do comment. Thanks.

```
Class TeamWorker
    def perform
        Team.all.each do |team.id|
            ParentWorker.perform_async(team.id)
          end
     end
end


Class ParentWorker
    def perform(team_id)
        assets_batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
        assets_batch.on(:complete, 'ParentWorker#FinalCallback', {:team_id => team_id})
        assets_batch.jobs do
            Team.find(team_id).assets.each do |asset|
                AnotherWorker.perform_async(asset.id)
            end
    end
    def FinalCallback(status, options)
        #This should run last after all child jobs workers completes
    end
end

class AnotherWorker
    def perform(asset_id)
        child_batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
        child_batch.on(:complete, 'do_something', {asset_id: asset_id})
        child_batch.jobs do
            ChildJobWorker.perform_async
            ChildJobWorker.perform_async
        end
    end
end

class ChildJobWorker
    def perform
        #do some processing/work and return
    end
end
```

Comment: I didn't work with sidekiq batches, but can you not pass some kind of batch identifier to child workers (so that they append to the very same batch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are not associating the child batch with the parent batch.  You need to reopen the batch to add jobs and/or child batches.  You need to do this:

```
class AnotherWorker
    def perform(asset_id)
      batch.jobs do # reopen this job's batch, now child_batch will really be a child batch
        child_batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
        child_batch.on(:complete, 'do_something', {asset_id: asset_id})
        child_batch.jobs do
            ChildJobWorker.perform_async
            ChildJobWorker.perform_async
        end
      end
    end
end
```